# Is it possible to have more than one if statement in an excel VBA User Defined Function

Tags: excel, if-statement, user-defined-functions, vba

I've created the following function in Excel VBA:

```
Function GetBTM(bai As Integer, comment As String, amt As Double)
If (bai = 195) Then
  GetBTM = "Customer Wires"
End If

If (bai = 399 And Application.WorksheetFunction.Find("MOV TIT", comment) > 0) Then
  GetBTM = "Customer Wires"
End If

End Function
```

When I use the function in a spreadsheet, Only the second if statment works, the first statement results in #value. I believe my sytax is correct, so I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Multiple IF statements work fine in Excel VBA, I use them all the time.  I would check the actual text in `GetBTM = "Customer Wires"`, there may be an unprintable character in there.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help you?

```
Public Function GetBTM(bai As Integer, comment As String, amt As Double)

    If (bai = 195) Then
      GetBTM = "Customer Wires"
    ElseIf (bai = 399 And Application.WorksheetFunction.Find("MOV TIT", comment) > 0) Then
      GetBTM = "Customer Wires"
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so I need to utilize a Nested If Statement because the function takes the last value produced in its body.  I should have known better. Thanks again.